# Tests started failing with new version of testcafe where a http call to load a script has returned 500 Internal server error

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have testcafe tests working fine until version `1.14.0` and with the upgrade of the version to the latest (> `1.14.0`), the tests have started to fail and the from console/network calls of the browser, I could see that one of the call to get the js file, has failed with 500 Internal server error and a blank white screen was loaded.

Note that the same works fine with testcafe `<= 1.14.0` and the same call has went fine. And there was no other more information from the dev tools for the fail or there was no information in the application's logs as well.

The tests were run on chrome 92 with testcafe cli.

Comment: the size of the js script file that was supposed to be fetched by the api call is 6.6 mb, if this information can be of any help.

Comment: This behavior looks like a regression. Please [create an issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug-report.md) in the TestCafe GitHub repository and share a project example and test code with which is possible to reproduce the problem.